# WMI is being too slow

Tags: c#, wmi

Is there a way to limit the number of entries WMI retrieves with a WQL statement?
I say this because running a query to retrieve all Win32_NTLogEvent instances is taking forever! All I really need are the most recent events (for about a week, or 2000 entries)

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using to get the log data. Other queries such as Win32_Processor are nice and quick.

```
            if (Configuration.OnlyErrorLogs)
            {
                // If Information logs should be suppressed, only get events where event type is not 3
                WMIDataTemp1 = DataRetriever.GetWMIData("Win32_NTLogEvent", "EventType<>3");
            }
            else
            {
                WMIDataTemp1 = DataRetriever.GetWMIData("Win32_NTLogEvent");
            }
            foreach (ManagementObject Object in WMIDataTemp1)
            {
                this.Log.Add(new Log(Object));
            }
```

And the functions to get WMI data are as follows:

```
    public static ManagementObject[] GetWMIData(string wmiClass) { return GetWMIData(wmiClass, "", "CIMV2"); }
    public static ManagementObject[] GetWMIData(string wmiClass, string whereClause) { return GetWMIData(wmiClass, whereClause, "CIMV2"); }
    public static ManagementObject[] GetWMIData(string wmiClass, string whereClause, string nameSpace)
    {
        try
        {
            // If a where clause has been set, prepare the clause to add to the query string
            if (whereClause != "")
            {
                whereClause = " WHERE " + whereClause;
            }
            // Create a search query
            string query = "SELECT * FROM " + wmiClass + whereClause;
            ManagementObjectSearcher wmiSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\" + nameSpace, query);
            ManagementObjectCollection matches = wmiSearcher.Get();

            // Create an array to hold the matches
            ManagementObject[] matchArray = new ManagementObject[matches.Count];

            // If matches found, copy to output
            if(matches.Count > 0)
            {
                // Copy the search matches into this array
                matches.CopyTo(matchArray, 0);
            }

            // Return array
            return matchArray;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorDialogue errorReporter = new ErrorDialogue(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Where each Log gets stored:

```
public class Log
{
    public string Category = "N/A";
    public string DateTime = "N/A";
    public UInt16 ID = 0;
    public string Level = "N/A";
    public string Message = "N/A";
    public string Source = "N/A";

    public Log() { }
    public Log(ManagementObject wmiLogEvent)
    {
        this.GetInfo(wmiLogEvent);
    }

    public void GetInfo(ManagementObject wmiLogEvent)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Category = DataRetriever.GetValue(wmiLogEvent, "CategoryString");
            this.DateTime = DataRetriever.GetValue(wmiLogEvent, "TimeGenerated");
            this.ID = DataRetriever.GetValueUInt16(wmiLogEvent, "EventIdentifier");
            this.Level = DataRetriever.ConvertEventType(DataRetriever.GetValueUInt16(wmiLogEvent, "CategoryString"));
            this.Message = DataRetriever.GetValue(wmiLogEvent, "Message");
            this.Source = DataRetriever.GetValue(wmiLogEvent, "SourceName");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorDialogue errorReporter = new ErrorDialogue(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone using the code above, note that there are two places where it uses matches.Count. This causes the enumeration to be rewound to the beginning each time and iterated through, to get the count, then reset back to its original position. (You can prove this to yourself by setting the Rewindable option to False.) It's twice as fast to change the code "if(matches.Count > 0)" to "if(matchArray.Length > 0)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now using the System.Diagnostics.EventLog class as a faster alternative. Much more beneficial to the program compared to WMI.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use a `WHERE` clause to specify the range of the entries you want...

For example you could use [`TimeGenerated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the `WHERE` clause to specify a time-based range...

Another option is to set [`BlockSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.enumerationoptions.blocksize.aspx) accordingly when creating [`ManagementObjectSearcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thfx82tf.aspx).

You could use that to specify that you want 2000 entries per call for example - together with an `ORDER BY TimeGenerated DESC` this should give a nice result.

Comment: Can you expand `BlockSize`? How would that work; what does it accomplish?
And what can I add in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: By default, the log sizes in Windows 7 are 20meg, so it may take some time to enumerate 20mg worth of data and pass it back through WMI.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Granted; any way of reading the files manually and organising it into my data containers? I'll post what the container class looks like.

Comment: @CJxD `BlockSize` tells the searcher object how many entries it should return per call... updated my answer... HTH

Comment: @Yahia Looks okay, but from a quick test with the CIM_Service example, it doesn't seem to save much time getting 2000 per block rather than 2 per block. I'd also need to figure out how it would work in the context of my ManagementObjectSearcher solution rather than a ManagementClass method - which isn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 1):

Speed is not a strong suit for WMI.  It tends to be quite memory intensive.  However, the question has been addressed and there are a few things you can do. Check out [Why are my queries taking such a long time to complete?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx) from Microsoft TechNet.

Comment: So as far as I can see, there's nothing like a LIMIT statement to reduce the number of items it retrieves?

Comment: Correct.  There is no way to "limit" a query.  However, if you don't need to iterate over the data more than once, you could try the semisynchronous approach which saves a little overhead.